# Unable to get Ubuntu One working

Tags: ubuntu-one, 14.04

I can't find Ubuntu One in my Ubuntu 14.04 installation, i get this in the app center

```
There isn’t a software package called “ubuntuone-control-panel-qt” in your current software sources.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UbuntuOne for online storage doesn't exist anymore!

http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/

Comment: There are alternatives http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/three-alternatives-ubuntu-one